# Ploting groupby object of pandas using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science, data-analysis

```
x1 = df.groupby(['RIAGENDRx', 'agegrp'])['DMDMARTLx'].value_counts()
x1 = x1/sum(x1)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBSIh.png
i have this groupyby object and i want to plot countplot using seaborn any one can help?.
i tried this

```
sns.barplot(x= x.index, y=x.values)
```

but that is very diffcult to read. here is output.
[image: output of seaborn barplot]

Comment: Please provide your data in a copyable format and not as a picture. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can try rotate label text:

```
g = sns.barplot(x= x.index, y=x.values)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30)
```

Comment: thanks for feedback but its very difficult to understand graph as there any way to use gender as hue.